# move semantics std::move how use it

Tags: c++, visual-c++, c++11, rvalue-reference, move-semantics

```
#include <type_traits>

template<class T>
typename std::remove_reference<T>::type&& move(T&& v)
{
    return v;
}

void main()
{
    int a;
    move(a);
}
```

Why doesn't this code compile?

> error C2440: 'return' : impossible to convert 'int' in 'int &&'

Comment: What exactly are trying to achieve by applying `move` to an `int`?

Comment: yes I don't know. It was just for example. But perhaps my example is wrong.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is straight out of the C++0x draft standard (§20.2.3/6):

> `template <class T> typename remove_reference<T>::type&& move(T&& t) noexcept;`
>
> **Returns**: `static_cast<typename remove_reference<T>::type&&>(t)`.

Consequently, if you change your `move` implementation to the following, it works just fine:

```
template<class T>
typename std::remove_reference<T>::type&& move(T&& v)
{
    return static_cast<typename std::remove_reference<T>::type&&>(v);
}
```

Answer (score 7):

`v` is an lvalue in the return statement (named rvalue references are lvalues, for safety reasons), but the return type of `move` is an rvalue reference (`T` is `int&`, but you remove the reference, so you form the type `int &&` in the return type).

You need to `static_cast` the `v` to `remove_reference<T>::type &&` first to create an *unnamed* rvalue reference, when you want to return it.

I'm not sure what your goal is. Either you want to use `std::move` (like you say in your title), or you want to learn how it would be implemented (like the code you show indicates). It doesn't make sense to try to learn how `std::move` works without knowing the basic C++ rules. I recommend you to have a look in our [C++ Books List](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/388242/the-definitive-c-book-guide-and-list). After you have a good grasp about C++, you can learn how `std::move` works.

Comment: unnamed rvalue references are also known as xvalues ;)

Comment: I have looked `std::move` implementation in gcc and it's working exactly as @Guillaume07 wrote (without `static_cast`).  So you are saying this is a bug?

Comment: @Ashot I know nothing about GCC or libstdc++ implementation details. I only know that the shown `move` implementation is wrong.

Comment: @Ashot: Maybe you have an old version of gcc that still supports binding rvalue references to lvalues? It fails to compile under g++ 4.5.1 here: `invalid initialization of reference...`

Comment: @FredOverflow  It seams like yes, I'm using gcc 4.4. going to update now  :). Thanks

Comment: @Schaub: I don't understand why you say T is int& here ? for me T is int.

Comment: The requirement that static_cast can convert to an rvalue without copying is pretty new (about 1 year). Older compilers didn't know about that!