# Initializer-list-constructing a vector of noncopyable (but movable) objects

Tags: c++, vector, c++11, move-semantics, initializer-list

One can `push_back` rvalues of a noncopyable-but-movable type into a vector of that type:

```
#include <vector>

struct S
{
    S(int);
    S(S&&);
};

int main()
{
    std::vector<S> v;
    v.push_back(S(1));
    v.push_back(S(2));
    v.push_back(S(3));
}
```

However, when I try to initializer-list-construct the vector with the same rvalues, I get errors about a copy constructor being required:

```
#include <vector>

struct S
{
    S(int);
    S(S&&);
};

int main()
{
    std::vector<S> v = {S(1), S(2), S(3)};
}
```

I get the following errors with GCC 4.7:

```
In file included from include/c++/4.7.0/vector:63:0,
                 from test.cpp:1:
include/c++/4.7.0/bits/stl_construct.h: In instantiation of 'void std::_Construct(_T1*, _Args&& ...) [with _T1 = S, _Args = {const S&}]':
include/c++/4.7.0/bits/stl_uninitialized.h:77:3:   required from 'static _ForwardIterator std::__uninitialized_copy<_TrivialValueTypes>::__uninit_copy(_InputIterator, _InputIterator, _ForwardIterator) [with _InputIterator = const S*, _ForwardIterator = S*, bool _TrivialValueTypes = false]'
include/c++/4.7.0/bits/stl_uninitialized.h:119:41:   required from '_ForwardIterator std::uninitialized_copy(_InputIterator, _InputIterator, _ForwardIterator) [with _InputIterator = const S*, _ForwardIterator = S*]'
include/c++/4.7.0/bits/stl_uninitialized.h:260:63:   required from '_ForwardIterator std::__uninitialized_copy_a(_InputIterator, _InputIterator, _ForwardIterator, std::allocator<_Tp>&) [with _InputIterator = const S*, _ForwardIterator = S*, _Tp = S]'
include/c++/4.7.0/bits/stl_vector.h:1185:4:   required from 'void std::vector<_Tp, _Alloc>::_M_range_initialize(_ForwardIterator, _ForwardIterator, std::forward_iterator_tag) [with _ForwardIterator = const S*, _Tp = S, _Alloc = std::allocator<S>]'
include/c++/4.7.0/bits/stl_vector.h:362:2:   required from 'std::vector<_Tp, _Alloc>::vector(std::initializer_list<_Tp>, const allocator_type&) [with _Tp = S, _Alloc = std::allocator<S>, std::vector<_Tp, _Alloc>::allocator_type = std::allocator<S>]'
test.cpp:11:41:   required from here
include/c++/4.7.0/bits/stl_construct.h:77:7: error: no matching function for call to 'S::S(const S&)'
include/c++/4.7.0/bits/stl_construct.h:77:7: note: candidates are:
test.cpp:6:5: note: S::S(S&&)
test.cpp:6:5: note:   no known conversion for argument 1 from 'const S' to 'S&&'
test.cpp:5:5: note: S::S(int)
test.cpp:5:5: note:   no known conversion for argument 1 from 'const S' to 'int'
```

Should this be allowed? I see no technical obstacles to it being allowed, but I don't have the Standard handy at the moment...

Comment: It looks like the only way to fill a vector with moveable objects is to revert to the old style: std::vector<S> v; v.emplace_back(S(1)); v.emplace_back(S(2)); v.emplace_back(S(3));` (or shorter/obcure `v.emplace_back(1); etc ...`). Sad, isn't it?

Comment: You can use push_back if the template type is MoveInsertable.

Comment: @JensÅkerblom: I'm aware; in fact, that's what my first code snippet shows. Sometimes, though, you want to use an inline syntax.

Comment: Similar question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8468774/can-i-list-initialize-a-vector-of-move-only-type

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Maybe this clause from 8.5.4.5 explains it (my emphasis):

> An object of type std::initializer_list is constructed from an
>   initializer list as if the implementation allocated an array of N
>   elements of type E, where N is the number of elements in the
>   initializer list. **Each element of that array is copy-initialized
>   with the corresponding element of the initializer list**, and the
>   std::initializer_list object is constructed to refer to that array.

So you can only initialize from lists if the objects are copyable.

---

Update: As Johannes points out, copy-initialization can be realized by both copy and move constructors, so that alone isn't enough to answer the question. Here is, however, an excerpt of the specification of the `initializer_list` class as described in 18.9:

```
  template<class _E>
    class initializer_list
    {
    public:
      typedef _E            value_type;
      typedef const _E&     reference;
      typedef const _E&     const_reference;
      typedef size_t        size_type;
      typedef const _E*     iterator;
      typedef const _E*     const_iterator;
```

Note how there are no non-constant typedefs!

I just tried making an IL constructor which would traverse the initializer list via `std::make_move_iterator`, which failed because `const T &` cannot be converted to `T&&`.

So the answer is: You cannot move from the IL, because the standard says so.

Comment: @sehe: it's a quote from the N3290 FDIS. I assume it's normative! :-)

Comment: I see. This seems to be a missed optimization opportunity in the standard, then... perhaps it will be fixed in the next version :)

Comment: This answer confuses more than it helps. Copy-initializing does not mean to "only copy but not move". Copy-initializing may well involved moving. It just means that you initialize as-if you had done `T t = e;`. `e` can be some rvalue moved into `t`.

Comment: @Johannes: I never said otherwise - I didn't say which sort of construction is invoked consequent to the copy-initialization. Do you have a suggestion for improvement?

Comment: @Johannes: So why does the moving not work, then? Is it just the libstdc++ implementation, or is there something else in the standard that forbids it?

Comment: I updated the answer to contain the real reason you cannot move!

Answer (score 9):

It appears it might be a compiler issue. [**This works in g++ 4.5.1** (*click for IdeOne online demo)*](https://ideone.com/bYhq9)

**Conclusion**: It was, in the sense that older g++ implementations did not correctly flag an error; initializer lists do not support moving their elements (elements are implicitely copied in the process). Thank to Kerrek SB for [quoting the helpful phrase](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7231351/initializer-list-constructing-a-vector-of-noncopyable-but-movable-objects/7232135#7232135) from the standard.

---

Old proceedings (for the sake of understanding the comments:)

<sub>**Edit** Found out that at least g++ 4.6.1+ seem to have your complaint about this code.</sub>

**Edit** Upon reading the source to `std::initializer_list<T>` I'm starting to get the impression that this is not supported by the library (it looks intentional). Whether the standard actually allows for an initializer list to *forward* the *xvalue-ness* of it's elements... I wouldn't be surprised if they stopped there (perfect forwarding is still not easily supported in C++0x I think, and not all initializer parameters would need to have the same (deductable) type.

Anyone with more standardese under his belt care to help out? http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2008/n2640.pdf

```
#include <vector>

struct S
{
    S(int) {};
    S(S&&) {};
};

int main()
{
    std::vector<S> v = {S(1), S(2), S(3)};
    std::vector<S> w = {std::move(S(1)), std::move(S(2)), std::move(S(3))};

    std::vector<S> or_even_just = {1, 2, 3};
}
```

Comment: This does not help at all (I get the same errors), and that's not surprising - all std::move does is turn an lvalue into an rvalue. Since S(1), S(2), and S(3) are already rvalues, wrapping them in std::move accomplishes absolutely nothing.

Comment: @HighCommander4: no, std::move turns them into `rvalue references`. Not the same thing. Let me check things locally. **Meanwhile**, head over [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5529881/move-semantics-stdmove-how-use-it/5529970#5529970) for some helpful hints/explanations

Comment: Pretty sure this is a compiler issue: https://ideone.com/bYhq9 shows it works just fine with g++ 4.5.1, with or without `std::move`. I suggest **using implicit construction** b.t.w.

Comment: That would be because GCC 4.5 doesn't implement the automatic generation of move/copy constructors correctly - it (incorrectly) generates a copy constructor for S even though a user-defined move constructor is present, and then uses it to copy the initializer-list objects. Add a private copy constructor to S, and you will see GCC 4.5 gives the same error now.

Comment: Have edited answer with findings. Thanks everyone for correcting; I've learned a thing or two about the compiler I'm using everyday

Answer (score 9):

The initializer_list only provides const references and const iterators. There is no way for the vector to move from that.

```
template<class E> 
class initializer_list {
public:
    typedef E value_type;

    typedef const E& reference;
    typedef const E& const_reference;

    typedef size_t size_type;

    typedef const E* iterator;
    typedef const E* const_iterator;
```

Comment: The language currently doesn't forbid to cast away the const and then move from the objects. But I consider that a language defect.

Answer (score 6):

It seems the answer is No per [Kerrek SB's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7232135/4339963). But you can achieve something similar by small helper functions using variadic templates:

```
#include <vector>
#include <utility>

template <typename T>
void add_to_vector(std::vector<T>* vec) {}

template <typename T, typename... Args>
void add_to_vector(std::vector<T>* vec, T&& car, Args&&... cdr) {
  vec->push_back(std::forward<T>(car));
  add_to_vector(vec, std::forward<Args>(cdr)...);
}

template <typename T, typename... Args>
std::vector<T> make_vector(Args&&... args) {
  std::vector<T> result;
  add_to_vector(&result, std::forward<Args>(args)...);
  return result;
}

struct S {
  S(int) {}
  S(S&&) {}
};

int main() {
  std::vector<S> v = make_vector<S>(S(1), S(2), S(3));
  return 0;
}
```