# Initialize std::map, using default-constructed values

Tags: c++, initializer-list, default-constructor

If I have a `std::map<int, char>`, it's nice and easy to initialise:

```
std::map<int, char> myMap = 
{
  { 1, 'a' },
  { 2, 'b' }
};
```

If my value-type has a default constructor, I can initialise it like so:

```
struct Foo
{
  char x;
};

std::map<int, Foo> myMap =
{
  { 1, Foo() },
  { 2, Foo() }
};
```

But suppose my value-type has a default constructor, but is unwieldy to type:

```
std::map<int, yourNamespace::subLibrary::moreLevels::justBecause::Thing> myMap = 
{
  // What goes here? I don't want to type
  // yourNamespace::subLibrary::moreLevels::justBecause::Thing again.
};
```

Short of a `using` declaration to make the value-type more keyboard-friendly, is there some way to initialise the `map` with a set of keys, all of which use a default-constructed `yourNamespace::subLibrary::moreLevels::justBecause::Thing`? How can I signal that I want the mapped value to be default-constructed of its type?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use [value initialization](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/value_initialization) to solve this problem.

```
struct Foo
{
    char x;
};

std::map<int, Foo> myMap =
{
    { 1, {} },
    { 2, {} }
};
```

Comment: I thought I could, and I tried it, and it didn't work... which is why I came here. Further prodding shows it works _in general_, but not if the value-type is not copy-constructible. Do you know why not?

Comment: @Chowlett Regarding your follow-up question, I will refer you to [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/7232135/7359094).

Comment: Ah. That would explain it. Am I therefore completely stuffed for initialising in this fashion? I note that even `myMap = { { 1, Foo() } };` fails, for presumably exactly the same reason.

Comment: @Chowlett If you don't have a copy constructor, you will have a bad time with initializer lists. Consider asking a separate question on how to work around this problem. Include what you've tried so far.

Comment: additional info: Since `C++11`

Answer (score 0):

You could make a function that returns an instance of "yourNamespace::subLibrary::moreLevels::justBecause::Thing".